# Show that $\Lambda(t)\le-\frac C2\Lambda'(t)$ if and only if $e^{2t/C}\Lambda(t)$ is nonincreasing

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives

Let $\Lambda\in C^1([0,\infty))$ and $C>0$. Why does $$\Lambda(t)\le-\frac C2\Lambda'(t)\;\;\;\text{for all }t>0$$ hold if and only if $e^{2t/C}\Lambda(t)$ is nonincreasing in $t$?

Is this just an application of Grönwall's inequality?

Comment: What happens if you differentiate the function $t\mapsto e^{2t/C}\Lambda(t)$ ?

Comment: I would say that Rebellos' and MPW's answers are (and Max' comment hints at) (parts of) a proof of Grönwall's inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{2t/C}\Lambda(t)$ is nonincreasing if and only if
$$(e^{2t/C}\Lambda(t))' \leq 0$$
$$\tfrac2Ce^{2t/C}\Lambda(t) + e^{2t/C}\Lambda'(t)\leq 0$$
$$\tfrac2Ce^{2t/C}\Lambda(t) \leq -e^{2t/C}\Lambda'(t)$$
Since we are told $C>0$, we then have
$$e^{2t/C}\Lambda(t) \leq -\tfrac C2e^{2t/C}\Lambda'(t)$$
$$\Lambda(t) \leq -\tfrac C2\Lambda'(t)$$
as required.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

Note that :

$$Λ(t) + \frac{C}{2}Λ'(t) \leq 0 \Leftrightarrow \left( Λ(t)e^{\frac{C}{2}t} \right)' \leq 0$$